# Overlaying ggplot2 barchart while displaying and grouping different metrics

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I currently want to display different metrics obtained from running some experiments using different models, methods and corpora. What I have so far is after I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484868/overlayed-ggplot2-barchart-with-2-groups).

My problem is now: how can I group the 3 metrics for each method so that they touch each other while having a gap between each method group? How can I get the proper labels back, maybe O, P, R under each and then below each group the method name (or a better way)?

In reality, I have many more observations, that is why I try to find a compact way to display all of them space-efficiently. Suggestions for a different visualizations are also welcome.

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(15)

models <- c("Model1", "Model2")
methods <- c("Method1", "Method2")
corpora <- c("Corpus1", "Corpus2")

n <- length(models) * length(methods) * length(corpora)
df <- expand.grid(model = models, method= methods, corpus =corpora) %>%
  add_column(
    overall = runif(n = n, min = 0, max = .8),
    precision = runif(n = n, min = 0, max = .8),
    recall = runif(n = n, min = 0, max = .8),
  )

#   Model1  Method1 Corpus1 0,481691    0,549785    0,357955
#   Model2  Method1 Corpus1 0,156035    0,665143    0,771734
#   Model1  Method2 Corpus1 0,773167    0,0837355   0,112950
#   Model2  Method2 Corpus1 0,520724    0,516921    0,621370
#   Model1  Method1 Corpus2 0,293658    0,407272    0,642982
#   Model2  Method1 Corpus2 0,791087    0,565303    0,634677
#   Model1  Method2 Corpus2 0,652155    0,689851    0,286050
#   Model2  Method2 Corpus2 0,203175    0,673428    0,0464008
```

I started with a simple barchart:

```
plot_with_one_metric <- df  %>%
  arrange(-overall) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=model, y=overall, x=method)) +
  geom_col( position = "identity") +
  facet_grid(~ corpus)
```

And then I extended it to several metrics, this is the plot I want am stuck on. I do not know how I could alter the labels in code and group metric bars so that they have no gaps.

```
plot_with_several_metrics <- df  %>%
  pivot_longer(c("overall", "precision", "recall"), names_to = "metric", values_to = "value") %>%
  arrange(-value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = interaction(method, metric, lex.order=TRUE), y = value, fill = model)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  facet_grid(~ corpus)

plot_with_one_metric / plot_with_several_metrics
```

Comment: Sorry it is not clear. You want to tweak `plot_with_several_metrics` or all of them?

Comment: @TarJae I edited it, it indeed was unclear. I want to edit the `plot_with_several_metrics`.

Comment: This is not easy. Have a look here, that might help <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690208/layered-axes-in-ggplot/25702640?noredirect=1#comment44443800_25702640>

Comment: You can group by methods and fill by metrics using the pivot you created in `plot_with_several_metrics`. Using that setup: `ggplot(aes(x = method, y = value, fill = metric)) + geom_col(position = position_dodge())`.